# /dev/sda5 : recovering journal, clean files block, can't boot into my desktop

Tags: boot, testdisk

to I face this screen when I want to boot to ubuntu. This happened after I used ''testdisk'' to recover some of my deleted files. After doing this a large part of my partition was occupied so that only about 3 GB of that space remained, and then I face this screen every time I want to boot into Ubuntu and it's just stuck on this screen
(Sorry for bad English)
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpV6h.jpg)

Comment: That message is informational. It's not an error nor a warning. You can ignore it as long as it keeps saying "clean". All Ubuntu installations show it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside your question. You are most welcome to answer your own question. Please use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below to write your solution. Please don't put (Solved) in the question title. Click on the gray check mark ✔ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your answer as correct and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this problem was that my /dev/sda5 was 100% full (as `sudo df -h` in recovery mode said) So I just booted to Ubuntu with a bootable ubuntu USB (You can use DVD too) and I chose (Try Ubuntu) mode. Then I moved the space-occupying files to another place(i could delete them too)
After doing this, only around 35% of my partition was used
And when I tried to boot to ubuntu again. I booted successfully.
I'm still not sure if this happened because of the 'testdisk' but I guess that wasn't really related with the 'testdisk' that much (Not sure anyway)